# Force Square Div

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to create two sections, one left and one right, where one of them is a image and the other one is text. They should always be the same width and height and always square. I use the Avada theme on Wordpress and trying to fix this with their Element Builder and custom css. No luck.

Here is a page where the resault is not square but responsive:
https://sundlof.se/devskargard/

I have found some codes that does force div to be square but they don´t take the other square in to the equation. If this requires jQuery, please tell me, I have not yet tried that, I really what to get this done with css if possible.

Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Regards,
Fredrik

Answer (score 1):

You can use *display:flex* to on the square wrapper and give it a height. This will always result in *flex-child* taking height of its immediate *flex parent*.
You can then plugin some media-queries to make this flex grid responsive using *flex-wrap* property

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
}

.section {
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="section">Section 1</div>
  <div class="section">Section 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Just go through following links then you will get an idea about the aspect ratios and responsive blocks.

[Learn how to maintain the aspect ratio of an element with CSS.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp)

[Aspect Ratio Boxes Advanced](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/)

```
<div class="container"> 
 <div class="text">1:1 Aspect ratio</div> 
</div>

.container {
   background-color: red;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 100%; /* 1:1 Aspect Ratio */
}

.text {
   position:  absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: white;
}
```

[Example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_aspect_ratio)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! 
I ended up to justify the square with media querys every 200 och 300px to keep it close to square. Not a beautiful solution, but a simple one.